# Swizzling have to be on main thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I am succesfully swizziling `imageNamed:` method when on the main thread.

Here is my code, it is js-ctypes: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/e8105a5f702dc9e6a4b8

I seem to be crashing when doing it from another thread. I'm not sure if it's a typo somwhere, I'm still digging but can't seem to find any mistakes. So I was wondering if swizziling with `method_setImplementation` is not thread safe?

Does the same thread safety apply to swizziling with `method_exchangeImplementations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an issue in your code but I can recommend you JRSwizzle library https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle and a demo how to use: https://github.com/kostiakoval/JRSwizzleExample

Comment: Ah thanks Ill keep looking, im temporarily doing the swizziling from main thread in production, until i can figure out why its not working from thread other than main thread.